# Is There any function in google's map api for android to locate a building (i.e hospital )using state name and district name and the name of the place

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Actually i am building an android app , which locates the hospital , and i am getting the data of hospitals from government website , but data from website doesn't mention longitude and latitude of the hospitals , instead it have district name , State Name and Hospital name.
Now i want to implement locator functionality , and thinking of using the above mentioned information available ,

so is there any function to query google maps using name of hospital , district name and city name?

Comment: Have You tried with Geocoder?  You can use ```getFromLocationName``` method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: I may help , i will try it! Thankyou so much for assisting!